# Add Regression manually

Tags: r, sjplot

[image]

Hi!

I just added an regression manually to the plot. But how can I remove the red part between the intervals?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using ggplot2, you just need an extra argument to `geom_smooth()`:

```
base::library(package = ggplot2)

data("mtcars")

ggplot2::ggplot(
  data   = mtcars,
  mapping = ggplot2::aes(
    x = mpg, 
    y = hp
  )
) +
  ggplot2::geom_point() +
  ggplot2::geom_smooth(method = lm, se = FALSE)
```

Make sure to add that `se = FALSE` there, that is what the red bar is. If this answer helps solve your issue please mark as correct.

**EDIT: for sjPlot PACKAGE**

Use the following argument:

```
ci.lvl = NA
```

Comment: I am using the package=sjPlot and the argument "plot_model". Is there any other option?

Comment: There does appear to be a "se = FALSE" argument for the sjPlot::plot_model() function, as well as a "ci.lvl = NA" argument, try those to see what happens.

Comment: Thank you! "ci.lvl=NA" worked!

Comment: Great! I added the solution to the original answer I gave, please mark as correct for future users looking for an answer for this.

Comment: I already marked it as correct :) Maybe you can have a look at my edit?

Comment: Hello - If you need to ask a new question I'd recommend opening a new question thread, so that this one doesn't become too confusing. Once a new thread is open, others and I can review it.